# How to scroll a div with Puppeteer (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scroll, puppeteer

I use Node.js and Puppeteer and I need to scroll a list. There is a `div` that opens with a popup. This `div` is characterized by a class named `"istrq"`.
I've tried to use some code found here, but I can't get the complete list into the popup. This is the unique piece of code that scroll just a bit:

```
async function scrollDiv() {
  try {
     const scrollStep = 250
     await page.$eval(`div.istrq`,
       e => {
         e.scrollTop = e.scrollTop + 200;
         return e;
       }
     )
  } catch (error) { console.log(error); }
}
```

How can I scroll until the end of the popup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nodeJS native function

```
scrollIntoView()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

So if you want to scroll strict to this element (with ex align to top):

```js
function scrollToElement(page, element) {
  await page.evaluate(elem => {
    elem.scrollIntoView(true)
}, element}
```

Comment: I've tried but, in the first case, in Chromium console I obtain "Uncaught TypeError: elements.scrollIntoView is not a function"; in second case, the execution remains blocked. How can I do?

Comment: I've forgot about async.
async function scrollToElement.
This should work if element is visible